# Displaying decimal values retrieved from Sql Server Database with thousands seperator on an Asp.net/Mvc Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET/MVC application and I fall into this issue. I am using decimal data type to store my data in the Microsoft SQL Server Database, say fieldname is `Volume`.
I want to retrieve this in Razor view say using `@model.Volume`. It is displaying quite alright however I want to display data in this format `1,000000.00`, `1,000.00` not the normal `1000000`.

Model Class:

```
public class Quantity {
  public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model.Volume
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model add the following data annotation to provide metadata to your view. This helps keep the logic for your model centralised.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}")]
public decimal Volume { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks I will try it out

Comment: @Model.Volume.ToString("#,##0.00")
I used the above code on the view and it is posting this error
"No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 Argument"

Comment: check if value is null and if using in edit mode use `applyineditmode = true`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToString() formatting features in your view:

```
@Model.Volume.ToString("#,##0.00")
```